# Build a string in MSBuild as a concatenation of a base string n-times

Tags: string, msbuild, msbuild-4.0

I have a numer, "n" in a property in MSBuild. I also have a string "Str" that needs to be duplicated n-times to achieve a final string that is the repetition of "Str" n times.

Eg. If n is 3 and Str is "abc", what I want to obtain is "abcabcabc"

Since one cannot loop in MSBuild, I don't know how to achieve this. Perhaps with an item group, but how do I create one based on a property containing an "n" count?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

usually for things like this I resolve to using inline C#, as it costs me less time than searching all over the internet to find a 'true' msbuild solution; here you go:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <MyString>abc</MyString>
    <Count>3</Count>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <UsingTask TaskName="RepeatString" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll">
    <ParameterGroup>
      <s ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
      <n ParameterType="System.Int32" Required="true" />
      <result ParameterType="System.String" Output="true" />
    </ParameterGroup>
    <Task>
      <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs"><![CDATA[
        result = string.Concat( Enumerable.Repeat( s, n ) );
        ]]></Code>
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>

  <Target Name="doit">
    <RepeatString s="$(MyString)" n="$(Count)">
      <Output PropertyName="result" TaskParameter="result" />
    </RepeatString>
    <Message Text="Result = $(result)"/>
  </Target>

</Project>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is of course a bit more cumbersome than I was hoping for, but it does the trick. As you say, finding a "true" msbuild solution is tricky.

Comment: That's why I have problems using these solutions: for me $(MSBuildToolsPath) = "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727" which has no "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll", even though I'm clearly using MSBuild 4 since I can use property functions?

Comment: that rather seems like a problem with your installation/setup? Did you use the exact code above, including the ToolsVersion="4.0" option? That results in setting the MsBuildToolsPath according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383796.aspx

Comment: Aha, no I did not use the exact same code, I integrated it into my own script, and it does not seem like I have the ToolsVersion flag set. However, setting it does not help, I still get the wrong path pointing to 2.0

Comment: It does work with your script as-is though, so there must be something wrong in mine, trying to figure out what.

Comment: Great, this now works fine. If no one comes up with a "native" msbuild solution I will mark this as the correct answer. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

To create a String repeated n times, you can also do this (at least in MSBuild Tools v4.0):

```
<SomeRepeatedString>$([System.String]::New("-", 40))</SomeRepeatedString>
```