# For Loop in MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, automation

I've done a lot of Googling to figure this out and learned that there is no real loop in MSbuild, just batching, but may be I am looking at my problem from the wrong side. Here it goes:

I need a string property that looks like this:

```
MyString,MyString,MyString,MyString,MyString,MyString (!!!Notice no last coma there)
```

The number of times `"MyString"` has to be repeated has to be settable.

Does anyone have a clue how to achieve it.

Comment: Just thought I can possibly use embedded c# in there to achieve this... but hope there is a simpler solution. To add more details, I have a number of files that are read into an ItemGroup, I need to repeat the preset string separated by coma and make it a property as many times as many files I have.

Comment: Do what this guy did, but with String.Join rather than String.Concat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156540/build-a-string-in-msbuild-as-a-concatenation-of-a-base-string-n-times